# Jquery Mobile Framework Alternatives for HTML 5 Mobile Apps

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile, windows-phone-8

I am making a Windows 8 Phone app using HTML 5 project template.

So for the mobile template after searching a little on the internet, I came across this framework called "[Jquery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/)", I really liked the framework's ability to allow devs to create and download HTML code using drag drop wizard.

Which brings me to my question, Are there any more such awesome frameworks available where one could easily drag and drop controls and then later download the HTML.

I also would like to add that I came across this another framework called "[Codiqa](http://codiqa.com/)". Unfortunately it was a paid one.

Please can you share any other free/paid framework which I can use to create a HTML 5 mobile app.

Answer (score 2):

[Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive) with the responsive feature !

Drag & Drop could be achieve with a simple [jQueryUI plugin](http://jqueryui.com/).

Answer (score 1):

1. Take a look on [PhoneGap/Apache Cordova](http://phonegap.com/) as a mobile framework - it will provide you with access to some additional native functionality + simplify a lot moving your app to other mobile platforms (iOS, Android, Blackberry, many other) - same code base, packaging, etc.
2. For the Html framework you can also take a look on [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/blog/sencha-touch-with-windows-phone-8) + for the jQuery Mobile you can take a look on special [Windows Phone theme](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Interoperability/Demo-jQuery-Mobile-theme-for-Windows-Phone-8)

Answer (score 0):

If your making a native app, using cordova / phonegap is great! It allows you to create apps with HTML, CSS, and javascript. Best of all, you can use external libraries for javascript. Also, its easy to use with many tutorials for setup.

http://phonegap.com/

Answer (score 0):

You mean the themebuilder? Kendo UI has that as well:

http://demos.kendoui.com/themebuilder/mobile.html